# Extract JSON data from Json Feed

Tags: android, json

I am trying to extract data using json feed. But I get NullPointerexception due to there is no JSONObject.

I am trying to extract following data.

```
{"postcode":"HA0 4TL","geo": {"lat":51.55135528090932,"lng":-0.29906534560684617,"easting":518029.0,"northing":184978.0,"geohash":"http://geohash.org/gcpv30whrm0s"},"administrative":{"council":{"title":"Brent","uri":"http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/E09000005","code":"E09000005"},"ward":{"title":"Wembley Central","uri":"http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/E05000104","code":"E05000104"},"constituency":{"title":"Brent North","uri":"http://statistics.data.gov.uk/id/statistical-geography/E14000592","code":"E14000592"}}}
```

I can create JSONObject as follow.

```
String in;
JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(in);
```

But how can I get postcode?

Following code returns NullPointerException.

```
JSONObject postCode  = reader.getJSONObject("postcode");
```

Comment: postcode is aJsonString not a JsonObject you should use getString("postcode")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
String postCode = reader.getString("postcode");
```